# File *.bbl is created but not found

Tags: bibtex

I used `bibtex` and created my `.bbl` file, but when I try to run bbl file by `\input` command, it said I cannot file `.bbl` file. How can I fix it?

```
\begin{document}
%\bibliographystyle{ormsv080} % outcomment this and next line in Case 1
%\bibliography{myref} 
% CASE 2: BiBTeX used to generate mypaper.bbl (to be further fine tuned)
\input{my paper.bbl} 
\end{document}
```

And the error that I got is :

```
! LaTeX Error: File `my paper.bbl' not found.
```

Comment: `my paper` or `mypaper`?

Comment: @HarishKumar my paper, it has space in the name

Comment: Then try to remove it or use `\input{{my paper}.bbl}` note an extra pair of braces.

Comment: I removed the space and it works, but not with adding extra curly braces. So it means latex cannot read files which have space in their names?

Comment: I got the same error recently. I removed the space from the LaTeX code and from the file's name. It worked!

Comment: A question: Why, after running BibTeX, do you include the bbl file by hand? Suppose your main tex file contains, say, the instruction `\bibliography{myrefs}` as well as a suitable `\bibliographystyle` instruction. The next time you run BibTeX (after running LaTeX first), the file `myrefs.bbl` will be created, and the next time you run LaTeX, the file `myrefs.bbl` will be included *automatically* at the location of the `\bibliography` instruction. What advantage is there in overriding this automatic procedure and, instead, including the bbl file via an `\input` or `\include` statement?

Comment: You could try to quote the file name if it contains spaces: `\input{"my paper.bbl"}`. In most systems nowadays it should work. But I recommend to avoid spaces.